# why does the XSL style sheet display html table with no XML (info/values)

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I'm trying to create an XSL style sheet that displays value from an XML code into an HTML table. The table headers show in the browser but no values at all.

Both xsl:for-each select="" and xsl:value-of select="" are linked to my xml code and I believe it's correct but maybe it's an xml problem only, not really sure.

```js
<xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0"
    xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method = "html" doctype-system = "about:legacy-compat"/>
<xsl:template match = "/">
    <html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <meta charset = "utf-8"/>        
            <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <table border = "1" syle = "background-color:blue">
                <thead>
                    <tr> 
                        <th> Calories</th>
                        <th> Fat - Calories</th>
                        <th> Fat - Grams </th>
                        <th> Saturated Fat</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <xsl:for-each select="nutrition/item">
                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="calories/amount"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="caloriesFat/amount"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="gramsFat/amount"/></td>
               </tr>                   
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

```html
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type = "text/xsl" href = "nutrition.xsl"?>
<nutrition:items xmlns:nutrition = "http://www.grandmascookies.com/nutrition">
<title>Grandma White's Cookies</title>
<item>
        <servingsize> 
                <amount> 1 </amount> 
                <unit> package </unit> 
                </servingsize>  
        <calories> 
                <amount> 260 </amount> 
                <unit> calories </unit> 
                </calories>
        <caloriesFat> 
                <amount> 100 </amount> 
                <unit> grams </unit> 
                </caloriesFat>    
        <gramsFat> 
                <amount> 11 </amount> 
                <unit> grams </unit> 
                </gramsFat>  
</item>
</nutrition:items>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing the namespace in the XSLT, so add it to the root element of the stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0"
xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:nutrition = "http://www.grandmascookies.com/nutrition">
```

and then use it in the `xsl:for-each`:

```
<xsl:for-each select="nutrition:items/item">       <!-- here -->
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="calories/amount"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="caloriesFat/amount"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="gramsFat/amount"/></td>
  </tr>
```

You had only provided the namespace prefix `nutrition` without the element `items`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the namespace "xmlns:nutrition" and use it accordingly.

There is no `nutrition/item` but a `nutrition:items/item`

You might take the short way and try `//item` (or use a wildcard like `/*:items/*:item` or `//*:item` if there are other namespaces involved)